# After magento version upgrade from 1.5 to 1.9.2.3 re-indexing not working

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, reindex, magento-1.5

Last day I upgraded my Magento site from 1.5 to 1.9.2.3. But after that Re-indexing is not working. On Re-indexing it throws error:

> Cannot initialize the indexer process.

I had truncated `catalog_product_index_price` tables and executed repair query for my db. But no use.

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: Are your permissions set right? Check permissions on `var/locks` and also empty the directory.

Comment: Its drwxr-xr-x. But I got a mysql error like `Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` ...

Comment: something was missed in your upgrade. it shows columns for insert into are different for column name and vaules

Comment: Yes. I think so. I had compared my working db with fresh 1.9.2.3 db and executed some ALTER queries. But still the issue exists. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Run this query on your phpmyadmin. It will remove junk id which is not required. Then reindex again.

```
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_datetime' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_decimal' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_gallery' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_int' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_text' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_tier_price' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_category_product' WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
DELETE FROM 'catalog_category_product' WHERE category_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_category_entity); 
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_website' WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity'); 
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_index_eav_idx' WHERE entity_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity'); 
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_index_eav' WHERE entity_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity'); 
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_link' WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity'); 
DELETE FROM 'catalog_product_relation' WHERE parent_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM 'catalog_product_entity');
```

Comment: Tried this but issue still exists.

Comment: Delete all lock files under **var/locks**

Comment: My var/locks folder is empty :(

Comment: then check the permission of that folder. May be magento not able to create locks folder for lack of permission

Comment: Its drwxr-xr-x. But except Product Prices  re-indexing all others are working. So will it be a permission problem?

Comment: 1. Goto the database.

2. Open table  “catalogrule_product_price” and delete last row called “rules_hash”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36492/discussion-between-asish-hira-and-dhi-m).

Comment: Let me know the result